# Warning: Division by Zero in PHP

Tags: php, warnings, division, zero

https://ctrlv.cz/c7pu

The error I am receiving, I don't understand why though. I have a feeling that it is something to deal with the $bank variable but I am quite new with PHP and I don't quite understand all of the code:

**PHP:**

```
<?php

  $thisgame = fetchinfo("value","info","name","current_game");
  $bank = fetchinfo("cost","games","id",$thisgame);

  $thisuserid=$rsx['uid'];

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(value) AS value FROM `game$thisgame` WHERE `userid`='$thisuserid'");
  $getrowval = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  $generatechance=round($getrowval["value"]*100/$bank,1);
  $howmanyitems=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `game'.$thisgame.'` WHERE   `userid`="'.$thisuserid.'"'));

  $profilele='http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/'.$thisuserid;
?>
```

Those are lines 77 to 90 so.... Anyone have an idea?

Comment: `$bank` appears to be 0 when you are trying to divide by it.

Comment: I don't understand why it = 0... Idk if it's something to do with the MySQL DB or not, but... Where it is $undefined in the picture, it is supposed to display the cost of that item... :(

Comment: may be you are not getting `$thisgame` , `var_dump()` to know what you are getting .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `$generatechance=round($getrowval["value"]*100/$bank,1);` with and let me know if it works

```
if( $bank > 0 ){
    $generatechance=round($getrowval["value"]*100/$bank,1);
}else{
    $generatechance = <YOU NEED TO DO THIS PART>
}
```

more better idea will be `$bank = fetchinfo("cost","games","id",$thisgame);` after this line check if you are getting $bank or not.

check if `$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(value) AS value FROM`game$thisgame`WHERE`userid`='$thisuserid'");` query is correct `game$thisgame` .

Comment: would you mind going a bit more indept with this please? Such as, what do I put in the else statement and how do I make it check if I'm getting $bank or not, I'm just now starting PHP development and I'm trying to understand the code but I honestly don't see the error. :/ Sorry to ask for you to basically do it for me but I really would like to see this tie together nicely. :(

Comment: @psychowolf94 Can you `var_dump( $thisgame )`  if it is correct then `var_dump( $bank )` this is how you can check if you are getting each of the variable correctly .

Comment: What should I put in the else statement though where you put, ( <YOU NEED TO DO THIS PART> ) ?

Comment: what `$generatechance` should be when `$bank` is zero ?

Comment: The person's chance should be 0% when bank = zero.... so I put this:          if( $bank > 0 ){
 $generatechance=round($getrowval["value"]*100/$bank,1);
}else{
$generatechance=round($getrowval["value"]*0,1)
}
var_dump( $thisgame );
var_dump( $bank );

Comment: then assign `$generatechance = 0`  in else part `$generatechance` should be zero if it should be `round($getrowval["value"]*0,1)` assign this.

Comment: you have left the semicolon to end the else part statement .

Comment: remove `var_dump()` s you are getting $bank = 0 , you can notice it.

Comment: Your query for `$result` also seems wrong, check that.

Comment: Seriously, thank you for the help so far, now I just need help with the price being showed as $undefined instead of the proper price... I don't know why it isn't reading the price, if you'd like to hop into a Skype call so we don't end up spamming the forum any more than we have to, that'd be great. If not, we can continue here.

Comment: My Skype = QuantumOrangeYT